# C++ generic class, why do I need .cpp file?

Tags: c++, class, generics, typedef

I'm looking to write a generic class (like this: `template <Class T>`) in C++11 but I was told that the implementation could only be written in the `.h` file.

on the other side I am supposed to submit some `.cpp` file. May someone explain the contradiction?
If all definitions and implementations need to be in the `.h` file why I need `.cpp` at all?

Comment: A `template` does not have a definition or implementation until it is instantiated.  It's more of a C++ language kind of macro.  (Or code generator.)  You can split the part-that-becomes-a-definition-once-instantiated into a `.cpp` file, but then it has to be instantiated explicitly in that translation unit for it to be linked against other translation units that instantiate the template implicitly.  Otherwise, those parts of the template won't have been instantiated, and the linker won't find them.  Quite the bother to do it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't need a `.cpp` file at all and there are plenty of header-only library examples.

However, it can be beneficial to provide `.cpp` files for some template instantiations since this give the opportunity to ship a binary another project can link against. This can save compile-time.

An example:

Your header `Foo.h`

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
  // some functions
};
```

If `Foo` will be usually instantiated with floating point types you could provide a `Foo.cpp` containing e.g.

```
template class Foo<float>;
template class Foo<double>;
template class Foo<long double>;
```

Comment: Thanks, may you help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62359649/c-generic-class-error-whats-the-problem