# C++ generic class error, what's the problem?

Tags: c++, class, generics, methods, try-catch

Why the following code doesn't compile?

```
namespace mtm {
    template<class T>
    class Matrix {
    private:
    public:
        class AccessIllegalElement;

    };

    Matrix::AccessIllegalElement{};
}
```

I'm trying to implement the inner class for handling errors

Error I get:

> 'Matrix' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration

Plus, if inside AccessIllegalElement I want to write a function that prints the illegal index what is preferable?

1) to define a function that takes one parameter

2) to give every class object a member called index to save that data

Comment: any help of how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`Matrix` is a template, not a class.  You need to let the compiler know the template arguments of this template when you declare/define inner items:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix<T>::AccessIllegalElement {};
```